# Error in custom repository interface

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to set up my first Java application using Spring Data for MongoDB in a multi-module Maven 3 project. Here are the relevant versions:

- Java 7
- mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.2.0
- Spring Data 1.1.1.RELEASE
- Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE

I'm getting the following runtime error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actorFacade': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private es.mi.casetools.praetor.persistence.springdata.repositories.ActorRepository es.mi.casetools.praetor.facade.impl.DefaultActorFacade.actorRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actorRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property insert found for type void
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:106)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 30 more
```

---

Searching in google I found people with the same issue and it seems to be related with custom repositories.

Here is the entity I want to store as a mongo document.

```java
public class Actor {
    public enum ActorStereotype {
        SYSTEM, 
        PERSON
    }
        private String id;
    private String code; // unique
    private ActorStereotype stereotype;
    private String title; // Short title for the actor
    private String description;
    private String projectId; // project this actor belongs to

        // getters & setters
```

The standard repository interface.

```java
public interface ActorRepository extends MongoRepository<Actor, String>, ActorRepositoryCustom {
}
```

The custom interface (where I think the error lives).

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ActorRepositoryCustom {
    void updateSingleActor(Actor actor);
    void insertActor(Actor actor);
}
```

The custom interface implementation.

```java
public class ActorRepositoryCustomImpl implements ActorRepositoryCustom {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void updateSingleActor(Actor actor) {
        if(actor.getId() != null) 
            throw new MissingIdException();

        // TODO change to Spring Converter
        DBObject dbo = (DBObject)mongoTemplate.getConverter().convertToMongoType(actor);

        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query(where("_id").is(actor.getId())), 
                Update.fromDBObject(dbo, new String[]{}), 
                Actor.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertActor(Actor actor) {  
        if(actor.getId() != null) 
            throw new IdProvidedException();

        mongoTemplate.save(actor);
    }

}
```

And finally, the application context.

```xml
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:properties/test.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- mongodb configuration -->          
    <mongo:repositories base-package="es.mi.casetools.praetor.persistence.springdata.repositories" 
        mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" repository-impl-postfix="Impl">                  
        <repository:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean"/>    
    </mongo:repositories>

    <mongo:mongo id="mongotest" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" write-concern="SAFE">
    </mongo:mongo>

    <mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.dbname}" mongo-ref="mongotest"/>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="actorFacade" class="es.mi.casetools.praetor.facade.impl.DefaultActorFacade">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I also have a little Spring test that fails loading the above application context giving the exception I listed near the top.

I tried adding the following but I get the same exception.

```xml
<bean id="actorRepositoryCustomImpl" class="es.mi.casetools.praetor.persistence.springdata.repositories.ActorRepositoryCustomImpl"></bean>
```

Has someone got a clue of what the error may be?

Comment: I'm using Custom repos too and didn't have any trouble. The difference is that in my spring configuration, the repository-impl-postfix property has the value CustomImpl. Try to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miguel's comment solved the problem. I had given the wrong name to the implementing class. I've seen similar questions around so I'll try to clarify the solution in the hope that it helps someone else.

I have the following interface definition

```
public interface ActorRepository extends MongoRepository<Actor, String>, ActorRepositoryCustom
```

The custom interface definition looks like this:

```
public interface ActorRepositoryCustom
```

So my error was naming the implementation of `ActorRepositoryCustom` with `ActorRepositoryCustomImpl`, expecting Springdata would pick up the implementation as its postfix is the default one *Impl*. The thing is, Springdata looks for `ActorRepositoryImpl` by default, even though what you are implementing is `ActorRepositoryCustom`. The solution is using the optional attribute `repository-impl-postfix` and set it to `CustomImpl`.